# Refactoring MemberwiseClone to use a constructor

Tags: c#, clone

I attempted to refactor the `copy` method to `copy2` like this:

```
class A
{
    public readonly int x = 42;
    public int y;
    public A(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public A copy(int y)
    {
        var c = (A)MemberwiseClone();
        c.y = y;
        return c;
    }
    public A copy2(int y)
    {
        return new A(y);
    }
}
```

(because the real version of this code did overwrite about half of the fields after the `MemberwiseClone`) and with the intention of being able to make `y` read only. This worked fine for `A`s. But we also have:

```
class B : A
{
    public B(int y) : base(y)
    {
    }
}
```

and `MemberwiseClone` correctly keeps the type of the thing it's copying, but my `copy2` creates a new `A` every time. What's the best way to create the right type, assuming the `B` otherwise remains effectively just an alias for `A`?

Answer (score 0):

My current actual answer is to leave the code as is with `MemberwiseClone` and then clobbering half of what's copied, but the solution I've come up with so far makes `copy` `virtual` and `override` it in `B`:

```
class A
{
    public readonly int x = 42;
    public readonly int y;
    public A(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public virtual A copy(int y)
    {
        return new A(y);
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public B(int y) : base(y)
    {
    }
    public override A copy(int y)
    {
        return new B(y);
    }
}
```